# Phalcon installation on ubuntu 16.04 LTS with XAMPP server

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, phalcon, phalcon-routing, phalcon-orm

I hope you have a good day, I need your help.

I do not know how to install Phalcon 3 in my version of ubuntu. I would like you to indicate to me every step I have to take, thank you very much!

Please!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should go the https://phalconphp.com. Follow the instructions for installing on Ubuntu.

Once you're done, go to /usr/lib/php/(some-date)/phalcon.so.

Copy this file to your Xampp extensions dir e.g mine: /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/phalcon.so.

Now, edit this file: /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini  and add this line:
extension=phalcon.so

Save. And restart your Xampp service...

Check your phpinfo() for verification of Phalcon activation...